# Where is the battery located on a Chevrolet Cobalt and how do you change it?

Tags: battery, cobalt, delta

I'm trying to get a 2006 Cobalt back on the road.  It's presenting the symptoms of run down battery (Dim lights, time on the radio is reset to 12:00, won't start).  The battery is original, so it's probably time for a new one anyway.  The battery is not in the engine bay, though it looks like there are terminals to attach jumper cables to.

Comment: All this is good and it is in the trunk but do you charge it from the trunk or in the engine bay somewhere as the book says

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The battery is in the trunk next to the spare tire under the carpet. You will need a 10mm socket for the bolts on the terminals and a 13mm socket for the bolt on the strap that holds it in place. A socket extension or deep well sockets would be handy.

1. Lift up the carpet.
2. Remove the hydrogen vent tube from the left side of the battery.
3. Undo the 10mm bolt on the negative battery cable and lift the cable out of the way.
4. Gently press on the clips on the cover on the positive cable and lift it to expose the bolt
5. Undo the 10mm bolt on the positive battery cable and lift the cable out of the way.
6. Undo the 13mm bolt on the strap and lift the strap out of the way. Note how the strap attaches to the bolt and the plastic spacer.
7. Lift the battery out of the vehicle.

Reverse the procedure to install a new battery. Note that you will lose your radio presets and possibly any current fault codes. I think the radio is tied to the vehicle VIN, so you should not have to worry about any lock codes or anti-theft procedures there.

There is a [writeup](http://www.yourcobalt.com/forums/maintenance/17425-how-change-battery-your-cobalt.html) with pictures at the yourcobalt.com forums. It says to disconnect the positive terminal first, but I was always taught 'Last on First Off' for the negative cable on batteries.

If you don't have a nice long socket extension, be careful not to short the terminals with your socket wrench.

I replaced the old battery with a Delco part from a Chevrolet dealer.  If you go aftermarket, check for the presence and location of a hydrogen vent compatible with the vent tube.  The vehicle will run without it, but I don't imagine hydrogen gas building up in the enclosed space of the trunk is a good thing.  Remember, lead acid batteries give off hydrogen gas when charging.

Comment: Looks like you found the same link I did.  Glad you found the battery.  Good luck with the replacement process.

Answer (score 4):

My Volvo has a similar setup in the engine compartment.  It's battery is in the trunk.  Try checking where the spare tire would be.

---

*EDIT*

I found some helpful advice on changing the Cobalt's battery at [yourcobalt.com](http://www.yourcobalt.com/forums/maintenance/17425-how-change-battery-your-cobalt.html).

> So, as we all know the battery for the Cobalt is located in the truck
>   of the car. Its about a 20 minute deal to replace the battery.

...they continue on with step by step instructions.

Comment: The battery for this car (Chevy Cobalt) is definitely in the trunk.